# wp_dropdown_categories by date?

Tags: date-time, categories

Is there any way to specify a time period for wp_dropdown_categories or wp_list_categories or something else...? I want to create a archive page, so that if your in the archive of 2010, you'll see only the categories wich were used in 2010.

do i have to write a custom function for this one? if yes, any suggestion where start?

tnx for any kind of answer!

best regards,

kris

Answer (score 1):

I have a fancy function that i made just for that:

```
<?php
/* Create taxomony term list of posts based on given year 
*
* @param $year - (int) 4 digits - the year to return the list of. required
*
* @param $taxonomy - (string) the taxonomy name of which the retreve the terms. required
* 
* @param $echo_out - (boolean) true - to echo false to return default false.
* 
* @param $type - (array) of args that tels the function what to get.
*
* examples: 
select dropdownlist:
'type' => 'select', //(string)
'name' => 'cat', //(string) name of the select dropdown.
'js' => ture // (boolean) wheter or not to pring out onchange javascript redirect function.

list:
'type' => 'list', //(string)
'before_list' => '<ul>', //(string) html tag (<ul>,<div> you can add classes here).
'after_list' => '</ul>', //(string) html tag (</ul>,</div>)
'before_link' => '<li>', //(string) html tag (<li>,<div>,<span> you can add classes here).
'after_link' => '</li>' //(string) html tag (</li>,</div>,</span>,<br/>).

return array:
'type' => 'return-list', //(string)
'return' => 'ID' // (string) what to return (accepts ID or name).



*/
function yearly_taxonomy_list($year,$type, $taxonomy,$echo_out = false){

    $args = array(
        'year' => $year,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $cats = array();
    while ($the_query->have_posts()){
        $the_query->the_post();
        $curent_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy);
        foreach ($curent_cats as $c){
            if (!in_array($c,$cats)){
                $cats[] = $c;
            }
        }
    }
    //dropdown
    if (isset($type['type']) && $type['type'] =='select'){
        $out = '<select name="'.$type['name'].'" id="'.$type['name'].'" >';
        foreach ($cats as $cd){
            $out .= '<option value='.get_term_link( $cd->term_id, $taxonomy ).'">'.$cd->name.'</option>';
        }
        $out .= '</select>';

        if($type['js']){
            $js = '<script type="text/javascript">
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("'.$name.'");
            function onCatChange() {
                if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                    location.href = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
                }
            }
            dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
            </script>';
            $out .=  $js;
        }
    }elseif (isset($type['type']) && $type['type'] =='list'){
        $out = $type['before_list'];
        foreach ($cats as $cd){
            $out .= $type['before_link'].'<a href="'.get_term_link( $cd->term_id, $taxonomy ).'">'.$cd->name.'</a>'.$type['after_link'];
        }
        $out .= $type['after_list'];
    }
    //return array
    elseif (isset($type['type']) && $type['type'] =='return-list'){
        //array of  IDS
        if ($type['return'] =='ID'){
            foreach ($cats as $cd){
                $out[] = $cd->term_id;
            }
        }
        //array of  names
        if ($type['return'] =='name'){
            foreach ($cats as $cd){
                $out[] = $cd->name;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
    else{
        $out = 'something went worng';
    }
    if($echo_out){
        echo $out;
    }else{
        return $out;
    }
}
?>
```

### Usage:

```
<?php
// category dropdown with JavaScript OnChange redirect
$type=array('type' => 'select', 'name' => 'cat','js' => ture );
yearly_taxonomy_list(2010,$type, 'category' ,true);

//unordered list of categories
$type=array(
'type' => 'list', 
'before_list' => '<ul class="yearly-cats">', 
'after_list' => '</ul>', 
'before_link' => '<li>',
'after_link' => '</li>');
yearly_taxonomy_list(2010,$type, 'category' ,true);

//return array ids of categories 
$type=array('type' => 'return-list', 'return' => 'ID');
$cat_ids = yearly_taxonomy_list(2010,$type, 'category' ,true);
?>
```

Comment: Great! Tnx Bainternet! I kinda made my own function already, but i will definitely give yours a try, cos it's looks better that mine, mine is kinda query heavy :)